# Ruby logging in realtime

Tags: ruby, logging, tail, puts

I am trying to log some output to a file in realtime using Ruby. I would like to be able to do a tail -f on the log file and watch the output get written. At the moment the file only gets written to once I stop the ruby script. What I am trying to do seems straight forward.

I create the logfile

```
log = File.open(logFileName, "a")
```

I later write to it using:

```
log.puts "#{variable}"
```

Again, the log file gets created and the correct entries are in it but only once I have stopped the script from running. I need to tail the log file and see in realtime.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally file input and output is buffered to a degree. You can disable this behaviour by flipping a flag:

```
log.sync = true
```

This disables buffering by forcing a `flush` operation after each write. With that enabled, programs like `tail -f` can read the data in real-time.